# Implementing barcode scanner in my (WPF MVVM ) application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, barcode

I am stuck at a point in my WPF MVVM Application.
My application must get the barcode data scanned by user (USB Barcode scanner) and compare the scanned data with my DB. I have a text box on screen and want to keep continuous focus on that textbox. user may go anywhere in the application but after coming back on main screen the focus must actually get on same text box.

I have implemented

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBox2}"
```

to my code file but it work only when screen loads. after doing some another action the focus gets loss. I want to get it back the focus back after closing another window or when he come back to main screen.

I have tried by giving TextBox2.Focus(); after all action is done but wont work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown) from the window and set the focus to the `TextBox`

```cs
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if ( !BarcodeTextBox.IsFocused && BarcodeTextBox.Focusable )
    {
        BarcodeTextBox.SelectAll();
        BarcodeTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

You may want to filter out some keys as f.i. ENTER etc.